# Istio limit access to Google cloud resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, istio

I have a service running o Google Container Engine(Kubernetes). It access Google Cloud Storage and works fine.

On the same Kubernetes cluster, I installed Istio 0.1 following to https://istio.io/v-0.1/docs/tasks/installing-istio.html

I deploy my service via kube-inject
`kubectl create -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f myservice.yaml)`
But now my service cannot access Google Cloud Storage any more. I get the following error message:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.`

To me it looks like the kube-inject and the sidecar make something so my service cannot access information about my google cloud project I am running in. As far as I can see is the sidecar the only difference.

Service still works when deploying without kube-inject.

What can cause this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to configure access to your external services as explained in [Enabling Egress Traffic](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/egress.html): either as Kubernetes external services or to use `istioctl --includeIPRanges` to exclude external traffic from being controlled by Istio.